# systemd out of control starting service

Tags: systemd, coreos

I am trying to get a CoreOS system up and running stably on Microsoft Azure and am almost there.  My only problem now is that systemd seems to be out of control with regard to starting etcd and fleet.  When I run

```
sudo systemctl status etcd.service
```

I have a constant stream of lines reading

```
Nov 11 03:47:54 Services1 systemd[1]: Started etcd.
Nov 11 03:47:54 Services1 systemd[1]: Started etcd.
Nov 11 03:47:54 Services1 systemd[1]: Started etcd.
Nov 11 03:47:55 Services1 systemd[1]: Started etcd.
Nov 11 03:47:55 Services1 systemd[1]: Started etcd.
Nov 11 03:47:55 Services1 systemd[1]: Started etcd.
Nov 11 03:47:55 Services1 systemd[1]: Started etcd.
Nov 11 03:47:55 Services1 systemd[1]: Started etcd.
```

Same with fleet.  Nothing crazy in my cloud config, just

```
- name: etcd.service
  command: start
```

This is driving me crazy, and systemd is constantly churning at about 35% CPU usage, which is unacceptable performance wise.  What am I supposed to do to stop this?

UPDATE: Turns out it was my fault.  I had copy/pasted the cloud-config info from /usr/share/oem/cloud-config.yml and added it to my cloud-config.yml I was using to start etcd and fleet.  Apparently on Azure, there is an OEM cloud-config that then calls yours automatically, and what I had done had likely caused an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my fault. I had copy/pasted the cloud-config info from /usr/share/oem/cloud-config.yml and added it to my cloud-config.yml I was using to start etcd and fleet. Apparently on Azure, there is an OEM cloud-config that then calls yours automatically, and what I had done had likely caused an infinite loop.